# program(server) the problem is how i can stop runnig

Tags: java

I have memory this year the subject was (architecteur client/server).  I used NetBeans and Java.

The problem is when I press run(server) the program was running but it never stops.  I need a command for stopping the program.

I tried using the function `setSoTimeout(...)` but I don't knew how it works.

```java
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class serveur {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {
        ServerSocket server = null;
        Socket client;
        int portnumber = 1234;

        if (args.length >= 1) {
            portnumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(portnumber);

        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.out.println("Cannot open socket." + ie);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("ServerSocket is created" + server);

        while (true) {

            try {
                System.out.println(" waiting for connect request...");
                client = server.accept();
                System.out.println("connect request is accepted...");
                String clientHost = client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
                int clientPort = client.getPort();
                System.out.println("client host = " + clientHost + "client port = " + clientPort);
                InputStream clientIn = client.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientIn));
                String msgFromClient = br.readLine();
                System.out.println("Message recived from client =" + msgFromClient);

                if (msgFromClient != null && !msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {
                    OutputStream ClientOut = client.getOutputStream();
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(ClientOut, true);
                    String ansMsg = "Hello," + msgFromClient;
                    pw.println(ansMsg);
                }

                if (msgFromClient != null && !msgFromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("bye")) {

                    server.close();
                    client.close();
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException ie) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you running that second `if` statement (with `server.close()` and `client.close()`) if the `msgFromClient` _does not_ equal "bye"?

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: That second `if` statement says "if the message from the client does **not** equal 'bye', then we shuld close the server and the client connection." I'm just a little curious why you included that since that `if` statement is presumably doing the exact opposite of what you want it to.